# Pointer to Pointer

Tags: c, pointers, char

I am having a lot of trouble with this piece of code (I am not good at pointers :P). So here is the code.

```
printf("\n Enter the file name along with its extensions that you want to delete:-");
                     scanf("%s",fileName);
                                       deletefile_1_arg=fileName;
                                       printf("test\n");
                     result_5 = deletefile_1(&deletefile_1_arg, clnt);
                     if (result_5 == (int *) NULL) {
                        clnt_perror (clnt, "call failed");
                     }
                     else
                     {
                        printf("\n File is deleted sucessfully");
                        goto Menu2;
                     }
                     break;
```

Function that is getting called is as following.

```
int *
deletefile_1_svc(char **argp, struct svc_req *rqstp)
{
static int  result;
    printf("test2\n");
printf("%s",**argp);
if(remove(**argp));
{
    printf("\nFile Has Been Deleted");
    result=1;
}
return &result;
}
```

I am getting test2 on console but. It does not print value of argp / removes that perticular file. I am not sure what I am doing wrong. Please help me.

Comment: Here are something that could be useful http://boredzo.org/pointers/#dereferencing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `argp` is a pointer to a pointer char, and you are trying to use it as a pointer to char, try change your code to:

```
printf("%s", *argp);
```

You would also need to change your `remove` call to:

```
remove(*argp);
```

Answer (score 0):

I always found drawing pictures helped understand pointers.  Use boxes for memory addresses and a label for the box is the variable name.  If the variable is a pointer, then the contents of the box is the address of another box (draw line to the other box).

You are using pointers when you don't need to.  Your "deletefile1_svc" function doesn't manipulate the value of "argp" at all so it doesn't need a pointer-to-pointer.  Plus your "result" doesn't need to be returned as a pointer since it is simply a numeric value.  You also don't initialize result (it might be zero) or re-initialize it (it is static so it will remember the last value assigned to it).

```
int
deletefile_1_svc(const char *argp, struct svc_req *rqstp)
{
    int  result = 0;   /* Initial value => failure */
    if (remove (argp) == 0)
    {
        result = 1; /* 1 => success */
    }
    return result;
}
```

To call the function use:

```
result_5 = deletefile1_svc(filename, clnt);
if (result_5 == 0)
    // Failed
else
    // Success
```

That will make the code simpler and less prone to bugs.

Comment: I am using rpcgen. All variables and methods are auto generated. Can not change them.